# Get lat and long in two columns as floats for all points in MULTILINESTRING in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

`ST_DumpPoints(geom)` gives me something like this:

```
("{1,1}",0101000020E61000002DEDD45CEEB362C0CE1951DA1BC24E40)
("{1,2}",0101000020E6100000C94AD826F1B362C09D4B7BC72CC24E40)...
```

Where I want it to look like this

**seq**   **lat**   **lon**

1,      61.1,  -149.1

2,      61.2,  -149.2
...

I've played around with `ST_AsText` and `ST_AsGeoJson` which gets me closer but I would like to parse it with SQL instead of the text.

Comment: I strongly recommend "lon,lat" order to avoid confusion.  The ST_X() and ST_Y() functions can be used for this purpose with point data.

Comment: That did it for me. Would you like to write the answer or should I?

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup already has it covered (just take out the `ST_AsText` line in the `SELECT` clause)

Comment: Taking out `ST_AsText` would return the WKB (binary) representation of the point. You just need to do `ST_X`/`ST_Y` on the geometry to split it out as float values.

Comment: The whole *line* from the answer, through "wktnode," would result in the minimum necessary -- fid,seq,x,y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good example of this in the [documentation for `ST_DumpPoints`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html):

```
SELECT ogc_fid, (dp).path[1] AS seq,
ST_AsText((dp).geom) AS wktnode,
ST_X((dp).geom), ST_Y((dp).geom)
FROM (
  SELECT ogc_fid, ST_DumpPoints(the_geom) AS dp
  FROM my_table
 ) AS foo;
```

Returning:

```
ogc_fid;seq;wktnode;st_x;st_y
84;1;"POINT(1760789.64678326 5433999.35927963)";1760789.64678326;5433999.35927963
84;2;"POINT(1760016.74943794 5433941.5050153)";1760016.74943794;5433941.5050153
1;1;"POINT(1755882.28518908 5434644.98441615)";1755882.28518908;5434644.98441615
1;2;"POINT(1755953.62731641 5434610.42870749)";1755953.62731641;5434610.42870749
1;3;"POINT(1756017.76954237 5434602.51304863)";1756017.76954237;5434602.51304863
2;1;"POINT(1756055.96704621 5434673.63981803)";1756055.96704621;5434673.63981803
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for but I really just want a column with float values for lat and long seperately.  Could you edit your query to reflect this so I can approve it?

Comment: ...sure, but it's just removing some of what is being included in the selection: just do `SELECT ST_X((dp.geom), ST_Y((dp).geom)` and remove lines 1 and 2. I won't edit it in case the more complete version helps someone else in a similar situation.

Comment: If you eliminate the `ogc_fid` it significantly reduces the usefulness of the information (unless you only have one row).  There's no reason not to accept this answer as-is.